# Best python module for a Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I am looking to start a calculator project in python. The project is going to function like Mathway, Photomath, etc. However I am not going to implement a "Photo" feature, I want to make it text input based. The calculator has to be able to handle calculus and trig like inputs, and output the answer(s). My question is what is the best python 3 module to use for this project?

Answer (score 1):

to build  a calculator in python, you can import math. This can handle many math functions and i believe even calculus. Im not sure if you have already imported or not. sympy is another good one this.

```
import math
import sympy
```

Comment: I glanced at sympy, and there was another one I saw as well but I just didn't know if there was any one who had any experience with some of these modules. Also, is it possible to graph equations in python? If so what, modules what would be best to import for that?

Comment: From my researching methods, it looks like sympy and math actually do the calculus in the best way. If there are anymore i come across, i will let you know very soon.